# Draw vertical dotted line in react native

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, layout

[image: See image]

Can anyone suggest how to do these dotted vertical lines between icons in React Native?

Comment: Try something answered here [How can I display dotted line in react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55588821/how-can-i-display-dotted-line-in-react-native)

Comment: I checked but it is only one dot. If I want to apply I have to do more than 15 Views tags. It is too much code/

Comment: you are already tried `borderRadius : 1` ?

Answer (score 8):

firstly, you can search for the third library, if you want more style. I find the `react-native-dash` library. you can use like the following:

```
 <Dash dashGap={3} style={{width:1, height:100, flexDirection:'column',}}/>
```

then, if you want to define a component by yourself, you can use the style, and put it in
the pure component

```
export const DotLine = (props) => {

  return({
     <View style={{
        borderStyle: 'dotted',
        height:200,
        borderLeftWidth:5
       }}/>

   })

}

//then use it in other components
<Icon/><DotLine/><Icon/>
```